# Is it possible to record html audio generated with javascript to an audio file on the back-end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, mp3

I am creating a project consisting basically of a javascript sequencer which triggers html audio with Intervals and Timeouts.

I want to process and record everything in the back-end (while the user sees a "Processing..." message), and then use that audio file for playback.

I know there's a way to do exactly that by recording the audio in realtime, but I need it to be done faster and preferably in the backend.

thank you.

Comment: audio generated with javascript? never heard :/ can you give me the link to a web example or your project that have sound generated with javascript?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is that my javascript code is playing short audio stems (mp3), from <audio> tags, in a sequence, using intervals and timeouts in order to sequence them in a specific order.

Comment: I see, it's like a simple music compositing/DAW application, right? In the old time, it's a easy job to do using flash, so the mixing process works on client side. I still have no idea for best way to do it in 2017. But it seems online DAW studio like soundation & auditool are still using flash until now (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda The Web Audio API has been around for many years now.  I suggest reading up on it.

Comment: @Brad ah, of course the web technology has been developed so fast. I just have not done any programming in this field since a long time ago & wasn't up to date about it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  There's a specific tool just for this... OfflineAudioContext.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext

Hook up everything in the graph, schedule all your automation, and call `startRendering()`.

Comment: I'm investigating on it, but there's something I don't really get... does this work also with "setIntervals" or do I need to modify all my program to work with the WebAudio API?

Comment: @Chuck If you're using `setInterval()`, it's unlikely your program would reliably run across all devices today.  `setInverval()` is not something that works at a high resolution, and can be throttled whenever the browser feels like it.  You'll want to start using `.start()` and `.stop()` with times in the Web Audio API anyway, and yes that will be required for the OfflineAudioContext which will run much faster than realtime.